# How to change website url after user logged in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to change my website URL after any user logged in my website.

Suppose my website URL is www.xyz.com. Now if any user is logged in website the chane URL www.xyz.com to www.my.xyz.com

Comment: you want to change your `base_url` after use logged in?

Comment: I have already change $config['base_url'] but there are no changes in site